# GetMethodID for setNdefPushMessageCallback fails

Tags: android, java-native-interface, nfc

I was trying to set `setNdefPushMessageCallback` in the JNI layer.
For this I shall get the Method ID for this:

```
public void  setNdefPushMessageCallback (NfcAdapter.CreateNdefMessageCallback callback, Activity activity, Activity... activities)
```

Here is my code :

```
jmethodID methodId = (*env)->GetMethodID(
        env, cls, "setNdefPushMessageCallback",
        "(Landroid/nfc/NfcAdapter/CreateNdefMessageCallback;[Landroid/app/Activity;)V;");
```

I have alternatively tried just giving `Landroid/app/Activity;` as well. But I get `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError` Exception. Please help me what is the signature that I shall use in this case?

```
08-20 11:02:01.451: E/AndroidRuntime(24550): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-20 11:02:01.451: E/AndroidRuntime(24550): Process: org.iotivity.ca.sample_service, PID: 24550
08-20 11:02:01.451: E/AndroidRuntime(24550): java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: no non-static method "Landroid/nfc/NfcAdapter;.setNdefPushMessageCallback(Landroid/nfc/NfcAdapter/CreateNdefMessageCallback;[Landroid/app/Activity;)V;"
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using the wrong signature for the first parameter:

`CreateNdefMessageCallback` is an inner class of `NfcAdapter`.

Replace `Landroid/nfc/NfcAdapter/CreateNdefMessageCallback` by `Landroid/nfc/NfcAdapter$CreateNdefMessageCallback`

Edit: The correspoding signature of
`public void setNdefPushMessageCallback (NfcAdapter.CreateNdefMessageCallback callback, Activity activity, Activity... activities)`
is
`(Landroid/nfc/NfcAdapter$CreateNdefMessageCallback;Landroid/app/Activity;[Landroid/app/Activity;)V`

Comment: This does not work for me. I still get the same error. Is the signature for (Activity activity, Activity... activities) is fine this way -> [Landroid/app/Activity;

Comment: Hi Simon, Thank you for the answer. It worked for me. Only problem was with 'V;' at the end, this should be 'V'.

This has worked for me.

    jmethodID methodId = (*env)->GetMethodID(
        env, cls, "setNdefPushMessageCallback",
        "(Landroid/nfc/NfcAdapter$CreateNdefMessageCallback;Landroid/app/Activity;[Landroid/app/Activity;)V");

Comment: `V` at the end is required if your method return `void`. The last `;` was wrong